# how to read all Content Notes saved as 'SNote' (Beta New Notes feature) for a Parent record all users?

Tags: apex, soql, bug, richtext-notes, contentnote

I have been trying to read all `New Notes` (**richtext version**) via SOQL query in Apex Controller class.

The design specifications for new notes signifies that they are stored in as ContentVersion records just like Files but with `FileType='SNOTE'`. I could query `ContentDocumentLink` to query all `LatestPublishedVersionId` of new SNotes but when I query `ContentVersion` object for those IDs, I get only the record Created/Owned by the logged in user, even though the Note is being auto shared because logged in user has Access to it via Parent Record, and I could see them in Notes and Attachments related list but not being able to query them via SOQL.

Any way I can bypass this?

**EDIT**: (test code attached - Looks like a Hard Coded limit is applied when reading New Beta Notes, they only are returning for creator of the notes and not for other users).

```
public without sharing class NotesBetaController {

    public NotesBetaController() {
        Id recId    = (Id) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cid');
        this.readNotes( recId );
    }

    private void readNotes(Id recId) {
        try {
            set<String> cdIds   = new set<String>();
            for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : [select Id, ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =: recId and ContentDocument.FileType = 'SNOTE']) {
                cdIds.add( cdl.ContentDocumentId );
            }
            string qry              = 'select Id, Title from ContentVersion where IsLatest=true and ContentDocumentId IN: cdIds and FileType=\'SNOTE\'';

            sObject[] obj = database.query( qry );
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Total Notes: '+obj.size()));

            for (sObject s : obj) {
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 's: '+s));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage()) );
        }
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page**:

```
<apex:page controller="NotesBetaController">
   <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

Then Enable **Notes** in Setup:

[image]

Once enabled, open a Contact record. (using two separate user logins). Create a New Note from Notes & Attachment list. You should be able to see two Notes in the related list like this:

[image]

BUT in the Visualforce page I get only 1 record when opened from each user login:

[image]

I tried "**with sharing**" and "**without sharing**" APEX class keywords and BOTH return ***SAME*** result.

Is it a Hard-coded limit on SOQL fetching? The DOcumentation of Notes (beta) states that Richtext Notes are NOT Private, they are default shared based on Parent Record. It seems to be a bug/issue in api.

Comment: Guys does anybody have any idea on how to disable enforced sharing in SOQL queries? ... "without sharing" keyword isn't working in this case.